# algorithm: exercise 5.1-2 in Introduction to Algorithm by Cormen, Leiserson, Rivest and Stein

Tags: algorithm

Describe an implementation of the procedure Random(a,b) that only make calls to Random(0,1).

Here Random(0,1) generate 0 or 1 randomly with probability 1/2 respectively.

Random(a,b) should give a number between integer a and integer b randomly with equal probability.

Thanks.

Comment: What have you tried? Where exactly are you stuck? People are not going to do your homework for you.

Comment: Stack Overflow is generally not for helping you do your homework. The entire point of exercises like that is that you actually figure out how to do it yourself. If you can't, ask a fellow student or your teacher. Or better yet, read the material you were given along with the course (if any).

Comment: it is not a homework and I know a way to do it. I just want to know better answer. I am reading the book myself and not taking a course. So I do not have a classmate to ask. If I can ask someone around, why did I bother to ask a question here.

Answer (score 6):

It's enough to just do this for `a = 0` and `b` some positive integer (why?). You need `log_2 b` bits to represent `b` in binary. Now I've given you a huge hint: think in binary.

In general, if someone hands you a computer science problem and something in the problem can generate from `{ 0, 1 }`, start thinking in binary.

Answer (score 1):

Assume you had a random number generator that produced 0 or 1; how would you get a uniform random number between 0 and 3?  0 and 7?  Those cases should be easier to figure out than the general case.  After that, think about something like converting a RNG that produced numbers in 0..7 to one producing numbers in 0..6.  Combining those two answers will give you the general case.